# Acessing SMB servers with PHP (running on Windows)

Tags: php, windows, smb

I would like to retrieve some files that are stored on a SMB share via a PHP script.
Sadly, my PHP is running on a Apache server on Windows (we have other processes requiring running the Apache server on Windows for this particular project).

I saw this article : [Accessing SMB servers with PHP](http://www.smorgasbork.com/2008/07/23/accessing-smb-servers-with-php/), but it refers to a wrapper around smbclient, which is only available on Linux boxes.  I looked at [PEAR VFS-smb](https://pear.php.net/package/VFS/docs/latest/VFS/VFS_smb.html), but it doesn't seem to be working either.

Is there a similar wrapper system or class for Windows ?

Comment: Were you ever able to come up with something?

Comment: @Blakethepatton no, we had to ditch that particular project and I did not have the opportunity to fix it since.